# how can i arrange numbers inside csv file in ascending order and split it in seperate cells

Tags: python, csv, data-visualization

I have data in csv file where the format of the data looks as follow

```
30:2,29:3,28:2,13:3,12:3,5:5,10:4,4:4,11:2,3:3,1:4,2:4,31:,32:4,6:5,9:5,7:2,8:3,22:3,21:3,18:4,16:2,20:4,19:4,23:2,27:4,14:2,26:2,24:3,25:3
```

These are questions with answers. The digit before `:` represent question number and the digit after it represent answer to it. I want to write a python program for it so that this array is arranged in `ascending` order according to question number. I also want to split questions into separate `column`. Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by split questions into separate columns?

Comment: i have this type data in a column where each column has these data. i want to maintain a seperate column for each question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sort the data useing Python's builtin `sorted` function

```
data = ['16:2','20:4','19:4','23:2','27:4','14:2','26:2','24:3','25:3'....
sorted(data, key=lambda x: int(x.split(':')[0]))
```

Edit: per [Primusa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8112138/primusa) point of `'2' > '10'`, key will need to be converted to int

Comment: this will sort it by its string value, so 10 will be before 2. You need an `int()` around what is returned by your lambda